# Laravel Form::open() giving expired _token?

Tags: php, forms, session, laravel, csrf

This problem just started happening this morning and I have no idea what's changed to cause it. I have implemented a small search form in the top nav of my site and as of last week it was working just fine. This morning, it returns "TokenMismatchException" for every submit.

Through my debugger I can see in csrf filter that indeed the value of `Input::get('_token')` is different from the value of `Session::token()`. I can also view the generated HTML source of the form and compare the value of the automatically generated hidden `_token` field and see that it is different from the token in session storage (using 4.2's native file storage so those files are right in my IDE).

It looks like, for whatever reason, the value of the generated `_token` is always equal to the value of the token on the *last* session. In other words, `Form::open()` is giving me a token that expired one session ago. Or a new session is being created *after* `Form::open()` outputs the token.

I have been staring at this for a solid 2.5 hours and cannot fathom what might be causing it. Any ideas?

EDIT: ADDING CODE -

view:

```
{{ Form::open(['route' => 'search.customer_job', 'id' => 'customer-job-search-form']) }}
... // a single select field
{{ Form::close() }}
```

route:

```
Route::post('search/customerJobCombined', ['before' => ['csrf', 'auth'], 'as' => 'search.customer_job', 'uses' => 'SearchController@customerJobSearch']);
```

It never actually reaches the controller, so I will leave that out to avoid wall-o-text. Only one variable is passed to the view - it populates the select options - and that is done via a view composer - here is that:

```
public function compose($view)
{
    $result = $this->command_bus->execute(new GenerateCustomerJobQuickSearchOptionsCommand());
    $view->with('customer_job_quick_search_options', $result->options);
}
```

All of that is working just fine, though.

EDIT #2:
It was a really stupid error involving some debugging code (`Session::flush()`) I added days ago and forgot about whilst on vacation.

Comment: what type of server are you in? did you try to change session driver?

Comment: It's all happening on Homestead at the moment, so Ubuntu 14.04 / GNU / Linux. I did not change the session driver but I did update my vagrant box recently. I will try changing the driver to see if that helps ... Ideally I would not need to change the driver for this.

Comment: Changing the session driver (to redis) did not help

Comment: is there any middleware who may have regenerating the session?

Comment: Nothing that doesn't come out of the box with laravel 4.2. I have not added any middleware.

Comment: post the controller, route and view. i will try to replicate the scenerio.

Comment: Just added it, although I'm not sure this is where the problem is.

Answer (score 0):

It was an error involving old debugging code.